# Setting a global session cookie path

Tags: members, config, sessions, cookies

I'm seeing `PHPSESSID` set at `/members/` when I have `$config['cookie_path'] = ''` (also tried `$config['cookie_path'] = '/'`).

Shouldn't this config ensure all session cookies are set at the root path? I'm finding data I have in `$_SESSION` is not available at paths other than `/members/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Russ, did you clear your cookies between experiments??? Blank will cause the current path to be used (I guess PHPSESSID was set while you visited /members/). the slash should behave as you desire, but it there's already a PHPSESSID cookie set onthe domain before you made the change, this cookie will not overwrite, ergo the old path.

Might be wrong but worth asking!